# How to add smileys in a chat application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I am creating a chat application in Delphi xe3 using  firemonkey.
I am using TMemo for displaying chat messages, so I want to add smileys to the Memobox.

I found this example (http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1147) but it's for Delphi 7, I tried to convert it but it's not working. No smiley displayed.

Comment: You're asking about a sample that clearly says it uses a TRichEdit, and you're saying you used a TMemo. Your confusion is not something that other people can help you with. Secondly the original tip was clearly for the TRichEdit which is CLEARLY a VCL control (Windows) and you're asking about Firemonkey. So hacks for a MS Common Control (Rich Edit) are CLEARLY not going to work on a Firemonkey app.  -1 for no effort to even understand your own problem before asking.

Comment: Which platform are you targetting? Ios, osx, windows?

Comment: Platform is windows but i was advised to use fire-monkey for easy GUI implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A TMemo control is text only, and so your smiley will need to be of the form :-)

If you want to add an image you will need to use a control that can render images. For example, a rich edit control. And that is exactly what the article you link to does.

Of course, the article you link to is a VCL article, and you are developing for FMX, presumably because you target platforms other than Windows. And so you'll need to find a control that admits both text and images, and supports the platforms that you target. Without knowledge of what those platforms are, it is tricky to offer more specific advice.

Comment: yes right but in the example i converted the TRxRichedit(not present in xe3) to TRichedit and now no smiley is displayed.

Comment: I think I answered the question that you answered.